# Swift 3 conversion from Int to String

Tags: string, swift3

In Swift 3, the `String` structure does not seem to have an initializer `init(_: Int)` that will allow the conversion from an `Int` to a `String`. My question is why does `let i = String(3)` work? What `String` method or initializer is it calling? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's calling [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1641295-init) (or [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1641845-init) for `UnsignedInteger`) arguments  of the [`String`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string) class.

Rather than defining separate initializers for `Int`, `Int64`, `Int32`, `Int16`, `Int8`, `UInt`, `UInt64`, `UInt32`, `UInt16`, and `UInt8`, Apple made two generic initializers: one for `SignedInteger` types, and one for `UnsignedInteger` types.

Answer (score 35):

For anyone just looking to convert an int to string in Swift 3:

```
let text = "\(myInt)"
```

Comment: Your response did not address the question

Comment: agree with the comment but this did help me with what I was looking for

Answer (score 6):

For people who want to convert optional Integers to Strings on Swift 3,

```
String(describing:YourInteger ?? 0)
```

Comment: It was the Swift compiler that prompted me to switch to describing, not me! not me!

Answer (score 0):

I saw this solution to somebody, thank you, to that person, I don't remember who.

```
infix operator ???: NilCoalescingPrecedence

public func ???<T>(optional: T?, defaultValue: @autoclosure () -> String) -> String {
    switch optional {
    case let value?: return String(describing: value)
    case nil: return defaultValue()
    }
}
```

For example:

```
let text = "\(yourInteger ??? "0")"
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to implement that... please?

Comment: I have UtilsView.swift, in this library I have other functions that I use in all project. A function is , infix operator ???: NilCoalescingPrecedence

public func ???<T>(optional: T?, defaultValue: @autoclosure () -> String) -> String {
    switch optional {
    case let value?: return String(describing: value)
    case nil: return defaultValue()
    }
}

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend this. `String(yourInteger) ?? "default"` isn't that long, and IMO doesn't justify introducing a layer of indirection in the course code (because inevitably your reads will have to go jump to read your `???`'s implementation, since they'll have no idea what that means)